# Back Button não aparece na NavigationBar XamarinForms

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin-forms, xamarin.android

Tenho um Hamburguer Menu com um ListView onde no Click da linha do listview chamo esse método para abrir uma Modal, porém a NavigationBar não aparece o BackButton.

```
    public async Task OpenModalAsync(Page poPage, bool bNavigationPage = true)
    {

        if (bNavigationPage)
            await Application.Current.MainPage.Navigation.PushModalAsync(new NavigationPage(poPage), true);
        else
            await Application.Current.MainPage.Navigation.PushModalAsync(poPage, true);
    }
```

Já tentei utilizar o método, porém sem resultado

```
    NavigationPage.SetHasBackButton(this, true);
```

Verifiquei que no método PushAsync ele coloca o BackButton.

Comment: No XamarinForms, a navegação tem duas pilhas:a para lha normal (paginas adicionadas com o `PushAsync`)  e a pilha modal (páginas adicionadas com `PushModalAsync`). Quando você adiciona mais de uma pagina modal o botão 'voltar' continua sem aparecer?

Comment: @DiegoRafaelSouza fiz o teste aqui e abrindo dois modals não aparece o BackButton, acho que para modal não deve ter mesmo.

Comment: Na verdade tem sim, eu testei antes de postar. Deve ser alguma parametrização da página, então. Só com esse código é difícil dizer o que está acontecendo, mas certamente o que você quer é possível.

Comment: @DiegoRafaelSouza, obrigado, vou testar aqui para ver o que pode ser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Caso em seu harmburguer menu você esteja na tela de "Root" ele não aparecerá mesmo.

Eu Utilizei no meu projeto de acordo com o item selecionado como PushModalAsync, neste caso não tem o botão de voltar, mas pode Utilizar como PushAsync

Você pode criar desta forma:

```
public interface INavigationService
    {
        Task PopModalAsync();
        Task NavigateToSubCategoria(Categoria categoria);
    }

public class NavigationService : INavigationService
    {
        public async Task PopModalAsync()
        {
            await NavigationHelper.PopModalAsync();
        }

        public async Task NavigateToSubCategoria(Categoria categoria)
        {
            await NavigationHelper.PushModalAsync(new SubCategoriasPage(categoria));
        }
    }
```

CodeBehind :

```
private readonly INavigationService _navigationService;
        public CategoriasPage ()
        {
            InitializeComponent ();
            _navigationService = DependencyService.Get<INavigationService>();
        }

    void OnItemTapped(Object sender, ItemTappedEventArgs e)
            {
                var dataItem = (Categoria)(e.Item);

                _navigationService.NavigateToSubCategoria(dataItem);
            }
```

Xaml:

```
<ListView x:Name="ListaCategorias"
          ItemTapped="OnItemTapped">

    </ListView>
```

Comment: Sua implementação é bem parecida com a minha, porém fiz um teste e o Hamburger Menu se não for Root da exception, tentei abrí-lo em um Modal, também se eu abrir um modal dentro de outro modal não aparece o backbutton, se tento usar o PushAsync que traz o BackButton me ocorre o erro "System.InvalidOperationException: PushAsync is not supported globally on Android, please use a NavigationPage. occurred" criei um projeto novo para testar e ocorre a mesma coisa

Comment: Por enquanto, coloquei no Appplication.Current.MainPage = new NavigationPage(new Menu()) desabilitei nela a ToolBar para conseguir usar o PushAsync, e ele está vindo com o BackButton, acho que a opção vai ser essa mesma

Comment: Deve-se então realocar seu Root para o Navigation.

var mainPage = new MainPage(); //this could be content page
var rootPage = new NavigationPage(mainPage);
App.Navigation = rootPage.Navigation;

depois disso tente dar o PushAsync

Comment: também pode ser isso que vc disse :D